# WCF client methods called from ASP.NET app return 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a library that contains a Service Reference generated proxy to a remote ASMX web service.  When I try to call methods on that proxy from an ASP.NET application, I get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
>   listening at https://domain.com/path/to/the.asmx that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.

However, if I call the same methods from a simple console app dropped into the bin folder (and therefore referencing the exact same libraries), it works.  I have the same, simple configuration in web.config and the console app's app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="ServicesSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpsTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://domain.com/path/to/the.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoap12"
            contract="TheContract" name="ServicesSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Tracing revealed no further useful information.  The ASMX endpoint is definitely available.  What could cause this behavior, and what other troubleshooting steps can I take?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a parameter issue.  My production code was passing null for an optional string parameter, but my test code was passing a guid.  The parameter is optional in the contract, so I don't understand why it triggered a 404, but I'm able to consistently reproduce the problem by passing null.

The contract parameter is defined as follows:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userdef1" type="s:string"/>
```

The 404 error threw me off from the beginning.  It's a reminder to always write your test code **exactly** like the code that doesn't work.